# Why Wordpress blog sidebar at the bottom?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

From couple of days back, I am looking that right sidebar of my [blog](http://umeshpatil.wordpress.com/) has been displayed at the bottom and at the above the footer.

Can anyone tell what css change will be required to bring the sidebar on the right side?

Comment: Hi, please check out [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997) thanks!

Comment: okay. Thanks.. I won't post again.

Comment: you're welcome to post, but do incorporate some relevant code here. Otherwise, the question will be useless for others once you have fixed your problem (because there is no code to see what it looked like before)

Answer (score 1):

i think you miss float:left in css

Comment: in .css file where is class/id of wordpress sidebar